# Multiple inheritance along with threading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, inheritance

I have a code sample which is very similar to following

```
import threading
import datetime
import time
import sys

class FirstClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'initialized'

class ThreadClass(FirstClass, threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__()
        print 'initialized2'

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        sys.stdout.write("%s says Hello World at time: %s \n" % (self.getName(), now))

for i in range(20):
    t = ThreadClass()
    t.start()
```

Due to  call-next-method of python I am not able to run init method of both FirstClass and thread. Is there any alternate way through which I can solve this issue.

Comment: why are you doing this? what is the code meant to achieve.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding Python super() and init methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-and-init-methods)

Comment: I have a class which does lot of networking calls whose tasks can be parallelized. More like it fetches lot of webpages each of which takes 1-2 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to call `super(FirstClass, self).__init__()` in the `FirstClass.__init__()` initializer too.

The whole point of using `super()` is to make passing on the call to a parent cooperative. In your specific MRO `FirstClass` is listed before `threading.Thread`, so without explicitly calling the next `__init__` in MRO order `threading.Thread.__init__()` never gets invoked.

You may want to look at the excellent [PyCon 2015 presentation by Raymond Hettinger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo) on how `super()` works in this context.